# Python 3 CGI: how to output raw bytes

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8, python-3.x, webserver

I decided to use Python 3 for making my website, but I encountered a problem with Unicode output.

It seems like plain `print(html) #html is a`*`str`* should be working, but it's not. I get `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters[...]: ordinal not in range(128)`. This must be because the webserver doesn't support unicode output.

The next thing I tried was `print(html.encode('utf-8'))`, but I got something like *repr* output of the byte string: it is placed inside `b'...'` and all the escape characters are in raw form (e.g. `\n` and `\xd0\x9c`)

Please show me the correct way to output a Unicode (*str*) string as a raw UTF-8 encoded *bytes* string in Python 3.1

Comment: Note that there are problems in the cgi and wsgi packages on Python 3.1. Python 3 didn't really become usable for web apps until 3.2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is that you stdout isn't attached to an actual terminal and will use the ASCII encoding by default. Therefore you need to write to sys.stdout.buffer, which is the "raw" binary output of sys.stdout. This can be done in various ways, the most common one seems to be:

```
import codecs, sys
writer = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout.buffer)
```

And the use writer. In a CGI script you may be able to replace sys.stdout with the writer so:

```
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout.buffer)
```

Might actually work so you can print normally. Try that!

Comment: This did the trick, but I don't really need to use the `print` function all the time, so I don't have to replace sys.stdout (and I don't want to, because this looks hackish). How should I "flush" the `writer`? Nothing seems to appear in the output if I use `writer.reset()` or `writer.flush()`...

Comment: Solved: `print(html,file=writer)`