# Python 3.1 server-side can't output Unicode string to client

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using a free web host but choosing not to work with any Python framework, and am stuck trying to print Chinese characters saved in the source file (using emacs to save file encoded in utf-8) to the resulting HTML page. I thought Unicode "just works" in Python 3.1 so I am baffled. I found three solutions that aren't working. I might just be missing a detail or two.

The host is Alwaysdata, and it has been straightforward to use, so I have little clue about details of how they put together the parts. All I do is upload or edit (with ssh) Python files to a www folder, change permissions, point a browser to the right URL, and it works.

My first attempt, which works on local IDLE (and also the server's Python command line interactive shell, which makes me even more confused why it won't work when it's passed to a browser)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.1

mystr = "世界好"
print("Content-Type: text/html\n\n")
print("""<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
<body>""")

print(mystr)
```

The error is:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: 
ordinal not in range(128)
```

Then I tried

```
print(mystr.encode("utf-8"))
```

resulting in no error, but the following undesired output to the browser:

```
b'\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd\xe4\xb8\x96\xe7\x95\x8c'
```

Third, the following lines were added but got an error:

```
import sys
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setdefaultencoding'
```

Finally, replacing print with f.write:

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open(sys.stdout, "w", "utf-8")

mystr = "你好世界"
...
f.write(mystr)
```

error:

```
TypeError: invalid file: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' 
encoding='ANSI_X3.4-1968'>
```

How do I get the output to work? Do I need to use a framework for a quick fix?

Comment: How are you running the code? Note that any solution trying to avoid is doomed - as noted in [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) (and undoubtly elsewhere), networking is *always* bytes, not `unicode`.

Comment: I don't think I understand all the details of how it's run. The account is in Alwaysdata, and all I do is FTP the Python file to a www folder (or edit with ssh), change permissions, then point a browser to the file.

Comment: Assuming you are using CGI, this is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515007/python-3-cgi-how-to-output-raw-bytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are using CGI, which is a stupid API as it's using stdout, made for output to humans, to output to your browser. This is the basic source of your problems.

You need to encode it in UTF-8, and then write to sys.stdout.buffer instead of sys.stdout.

And after that, get yourself a webframework. Really, you'll be a lot happier.

Comment: Thanks for both the comment and answer. The link in the comment had the answer to my question.